# Rails/PostgreSQL : query value inside an integer array column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

What I wrong with me or this query?

I have a Shop model with an opening days column, which is an array of integers (something you can do with Postgres):

```
days= [1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

When I query:

```
shops = Shop.where('days[0] = 1')
```

I get an empty ActiveRecord Relation.

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

When I take a shop with this kind of array…

```
shop = Shop.first
=> #<Shop id: 215, days: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],…
```

If I do

```
shop.days[0]
```

I get

```
=> 1
```

I really don't get it.

Comment: How did you define the `days` column in PG?

Comment: Like this : `t.integer :days, array: true, default: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: And this is how it "looks" in my database column : `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`. And the title column is days integer[ ]

Comment: What is the real query created and executed by Rails? Check the output in the console and try it on the PG console. Does it work?

Comment: The query is : `SELECT "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE (days[0] = 1)` and the answer is `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`. I don't know how to use the PG console so I'm gonna check it out ;)

Comment: The PG Console doesn't give me any error either. Just an empty result (I'm using pgAdmin3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *By default* PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of n elements starts with `array[1]` and ends with `array[n]`.
>
> — [Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html)

It's just your example. Your index is out of bounds, so it doesn't match any records, `days[0]` is `NULL`. Everywhere. Fire up `rails db` and figure:

```
SELECT * FROM shops WHERE days[0] IS NULL;
```

But what's with that *"by default"*? Is it possible to define array bounds on schema level so this never becomes an issue?

Well... it's Rails' fault, I'm afraid. If it's even considered an "issue" at all. In order for an array to be zero-indexed it should be saved as such in SQL. I tried that in SQL, it works:

```
INSERT INTO shops
        (days,           created_at,        updated_at)
  values('[0:2]={1, 1, 0}', current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

Unfortunately, Rails loses bounds for some reason:

```
 Shop.create(days: '[0:3]={6, 7, 8, 9}')
 > INSERT ... [["days", "{6,7,8,9}"], ...]
```

Comment: Ah, that would explain why this didn't happened yesterday ^^. Time.zone.now.wday = 0 today !!!

Comment: I'm researching if it's possible to set the lower bound to 0, since this is inconsistent with most of the other tools Rails developers use.

Comment: Thank you because my code was pretty wrong by one day. If I had enough reputation, I grant you the one I owe you.